# Nested Interval Property and uniqueness

Tags: real-analysis

Is the common element contained within $\bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} I_j$ where $I_j$ is a closed interval unique?

Comment: No, the intersection is not necessarily a singleton set.

Comment: It’s unique if and only if the lengths of the intervals converge to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider $I_j = [-1/j, \ 1\!+ \!1/j]$

With this in mind, what must be true of nested closed intervals $I_j$ if they are such that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{j=1}^\infty I_j = \{x\}$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$?